# Firebase crashes with Android Instant apps

Tags: android, firebase, android-instant-apps

I am trying to initialize Firebase(11.2.0) in an Android instant app using:

```
FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);
```

But it throws following exception stating jobscheduler is not supported:

```
      E/FirebaseApp: Firebase API initialization failure.
  java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
      at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zza(Unknown Source)
      at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source)
      at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source)
      at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source)
      at com.hello.world.myapp.provider.MyApplication.onCreate(MyApplication.java:93)
      at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1024)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5403)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap2(ActivityThread.java)
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1545)
   Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Service: jobscheduler is not supported.
      at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1684)
      at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1637)
      at android.app.job.IJobScheduler$Stub$Proxy.cancel(IJobScheduler.java:202)
      at android.app.JobSchedulerImpl.cancel(JobSchedulerImpl.java:60)
      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzcfj.zzazu(Unknown Source)
      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzcfj.zzuh(Unknown Source)
      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzcdm.initialize(Unknown Source)
```

I followed integration instructions given on android developer docs [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/instant-apps/guides/analytics.html).

Answer (score 3):

This may be a Firebase bug.  The same stack trace appears in this [Firebase Google Groups post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/EAF4KZsB7I0).  Ian Barber, a Firebase team member, replied to the post on August 2nd and said:

> We have found an issue where Google Analytics for Firebase calls
>   JobScheduler, which is unfortunately unsupported in instantapps. We
>   have a fix internally, but unfortunately it has to go on to a fairly
>   long release chain, so it will be several weeks before it hits SDK
>   manager.

I recommend you contact [Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/).

Comment: My app is very simple to firebase remote config and analytics. When I converted into the instant app I started getting this error: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process... and so on.  I am very much excited to launch my first instant app since the day it was announced in IO16. But still, I am not able to do so because of this. I am eagerly waiting for this to resolve. Kindly understand.

Comment: JobScheduler should be fixed now https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/67799672#comment3 If you're still running into issues, report your problems over there.

Answer (score 0):

With reference to [Google issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/67799672) JobScheduler should be fixed now 
The recommended approach would be to use the framework’s JobScheduler for API >= 21 since Instant Apps are only supported down to 21 anyways, and use Firebase JobDispatcher for the installed app for below 21.

**example** https://github.com/firebase/firebase-jobdispatcher-android

If any issue persists, please report at [Google issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/67799672) they will re-open to examine.